# Elegant ggplot to report summary data and trend at each time point in an RCT

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am analysing an RCT and I wish to report summary statistics (mean with 95%CI) for a number of variables at three time points stratified by treatment allocation. Below is my code so far which only yields this figure.

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 100
dat1 <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                   treat = factor(sample(c('Trt','Ctrl'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                   time = factor("T1"),
                   outcome1=rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.3),
                   st=runif(n, min=24, max=60),
                   qt=runif(n, min=.24, max=.60),
                   zt=runif(n, min=124, max=360)
)
dat2 <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                   treat = dat1$treat,
                   time = factor("T2"),
                   outcome1=dat1$outcome1,
                   st=runif(n, min=34, max=80),
                   qt=runif(n, min=.44, max=.90),
                   zt=runif(n, min=214, max=460)
)
dat3 <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                   treat = dat1$treat,
                   time = factor("T3"),
                   outcome1=dat1$outcome1,
                   st=runif(n, min=44, max=90),
                   qt=runif(n, min=.74, max=1.60),
                   zt=runif(n, min=324, max=1760)
)

dat <- rbind(dat1,dat2, dat3)

ggplot(dat,aes(x=mean(zt), y=time)) + geom_point(aes(colour=treat)) + coord_flip() + geom_line(aes(colour=treat))
```

I have three questions

1. can a line be added connecting T1 to T2 to T3 showing the trend
2. can the 95%CI for the mean be added to each point without having to calculate a "ymin" and "ymax" for all my response variables
3. if I have multiple response variables (in this example "st", "qt" and "zt") is there a way to produce these all at one as some sort of facet?

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot_longer should do most of what you need. Pivot your st, qt, and zt (and whatever other response variables you need). Here I've labeled them "response_variables" and their values as value. You can then facet_wrap by response_variable. Stat_summary will add a line and the mean and ci (se), after group and color by treat. I opted for scales = "free" in facet_wrap otherwise you won't see much going on as zt dominates with its larger range

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-(1:4), names_to = "response_variables") %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=value, y=time, group = treat, color = treat)) +
  facet_wrap(~response_variables, scales = "free") + 
  coord_flip() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal,
                 geom = "errorbar") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,
               geom = "line") +
    stat_summary(fun = mean,
               geom = "point")
```

[image: plot_output]

Comment: thanks for providing this. One my sample data it appears to work when applying it to my actual data I encounter some trouble.  Can you explain what the `pivot_longer(-(1:4))` is actually doing which will give me a better idea of trying to use this code on my data. For your knowledge, what would be my "time" variable is the last column in my data.

Comment: pivot_longer will put the data into long format. It will allow you to use the facet_wrap function to display a separate plot for each response variable. You specify what variables you want to spread into longer format, producing a column name of those variables as names and the value from each variable as a value, with one row for each. The -(1:4) I used could also be specified as 5:7. It chooses the variables to spread into long format. Equivalently, the negative chooses which variables not to specify. I chose the negative to allow you to have more response variables, but don't include treat.

Comment: thanks for following up. Unfortunately, I am encountering the following error message when applying your code to my data `Error: Can't combine `sbp` <double> and `time` <character>.` As you can imagine 'sbp' is the systolic blood pressure and 'time' is the time point at which it was measured. I checked the class of these variables and the structure compared to my MRE and it baffles why I am getting this. I'm sorry I cannot share my actual data with you but is there enough in what I've described for you to assist? I can take this chat offline to email if need be.

Comment: You're getting that error because you are combining those variables into one variable when you pivot_longer. You can see in your sample data above that sbp is a number and time is a character. You would need to convert the variable type of one of the variables if you wanted to combine them, but you don't want to do that. As I said, you just want to specify your response variables in the pivot_longer options. Time is not a response variable. See: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html

Comment: Thanks again for following up and for the explanation. Using your advice, I have managed to implement your code. Very much appreciated!

Comment: One final question - any way to add p-values for difference between groups above the points?

Comment: Great to hear it's working. As for the p-values, you'd want to open a different question under that topic or try searching by repeated measures manova or mixed effects models with repeated measures.